# MySQL join table return only one match

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm struggling the the JOIN in a MySQL query. Somehow I can't find out why my result is not what I want.

I have two tables, a table orders and a table products. The table product holds the order.id of the order. So a order can have more than one products, so for example the table products holds two records for a order.

The result I need is all orders where a product holds a VAT of 21.

Table example.

```
orders
id | customer
---------------
1  | John Doe
2  | Hello World

order_products
id | order_id | product          | vat
1  | 1        | Porsche 911 GT4  | 21
2  | 1        | Audi R8 LMS      | 21
3  | 1        | Ferrari Enzo     | 19
3  | 2        | Bugatti Veyron   | 19
```

No I want all orders where the products have a VAT of 21. So I will do a LEFT JOIN on the table order_products:

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.customer, order_products.product FROM orders LEFT JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id WHERE order_products.vat = '21'
```

This returns the following:

```
1 John Doe Porsche
1 John Doe Audi R8 LMS
```

But I only need one result because the orders.id is important for me, not all products in the order. I only join on the order_products to get the orders with only VAT 21. At the moment I ran out of options on how to fix this. Even after reading several topics about joins on this site and other sites.

Comment: use Inner Join intends of Left join

Comment: I did, returns the same. My real query is on a other table, these tables are only fictive, but the structure is the same

Comment: What if you have 2 different order_ids ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany, that doesn't matter, all orders which hold products with a VAT of 21.

Comment: Often, not caring which results are returned is indicative of poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: If you're returning either 'Porsche' or 'Audi' then you *should* care which of those is returned. Otherwise, you probably shouldn't be selecting that column at all.

Comment: @Strawberry, that's true, I don't need that data so the column should not be placed in the query at all! Your right about that!

Comment: In that case you probably don't want GROUP BY at all. The DISTINCT operator would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you aren't going to return any orders that don't have products, so there is no need for a left join...an inner join is fine.

If the orders_product is not important to you, you can use a subquery and not select any columns from the orders_product. With your current query, you're selecting a column though.

Something like...

```
SELECT id, customer 
FROM orders 
WHERE order_id IN (SELECT order_id FROM order_products
                   WHERE order_products.vat = '21');
```

If you prefer not to use a correlated subquery, you can use a group by or distinct

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.customer 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id 
WHERE order_products.vat = '21'
GROUP BY orders.id, orders.customer;
```

or...

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.id, orders.customer 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id 
WHERE order_products.vat = '21';
```

Comment: This also returns the right order, and the orders_products is indeed not important, only the `orders.id` and `orders.customer`. The answer of @Jim is also correct, but I don't know what is faster, a extra select or a group by!

Comment: Which is faster will depend on things like the cardinalities of the tables and may even change over time. If the performance does matter (premature optimization is the root of all evil, right?)m you should test them. However, you are probably best to pick whichever seems clearer to you.

Comment: On my database with about 120k orders and 150k products performance seems to be the same. So I will go for the `GROUP BY` because it seems more cleares for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the orders then you can group by the order id:

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.customer, order_products.product 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id 
WHERE order_products.vat = '21'
GROUP BY orders.id;
```

However note that `order_products.product` will only be one of the products. If you wish to display all of the products but in the one column you can user `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.customer, GROUP_CONCAT(order_products.product) 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id 
WHERE order_products.vat = '21'
GROUP BY orders.id;
```

This will return:

```
1 John Doe Porsche, Audi R8 LMS
```

Comment: Actually I don't need the `order_products.product`, only `orders.id` is enough. So `GROUP BY` is what I need I suppose!

Comment: I marked the answer of Steve Clanton as "answer" because it holds two methods, yours including! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.id
              , o.customer
           FROM orders o
           JOIN order_products op
             ON op.order_id = o.id 
          WHERE op.vat = 21;
```